# Distance from point to line with positive and negative values (near tool?)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, proximity

I am trying to calculate the distance between collected points and a generated shoreline, but I also need to know if the points are inside the shoreline or outside the shoreline. I have been using the near tool. As a polygon I only got distance values from the points outside the shoreline. I converted the polygon to a polyline so now I get distance values from all of the points, but they are absolute so I cant tell which side of the line they fall on.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: select the ones inside the polygon and multiply the distance by -1

Comment: I am using ArcMap10.5.1 and I believe I have the advanced license.

Comment: and yes I can multiply or add a (-) symbol, but I was hoping to find an automatic way to compute that to be more efficient and reduce human error

Comment: Since it is a line there is no outside or inside from a geometry perspective, however if you have a polygon of the shore area, it's just a selection.  If you do not have a polygon of the shore area, you could use a directional buffer (left or right sided buffer), with a distance beyond whatever your maximum distance is, to create a polygon for your shoreline, then proceed with the selection step.

Comment: Look in help at querypointanddistance method of geometry. It returns distance to line and also side of a line - left or right. Anyway, final selection by polygon as suggested is much more efficient. You don't have to check direction of coastlines.